# How to opens up one space at the beginning of the array(dynamic array)?

Tags: c++

I am doing some function with a dynamic array T

```
template <class T>
class MyVector :
{
private:
    T    *data;
    int  size;
    int  capacity;
    void grow();
    void shiftRight();
public:
    MyVector();
}

template <class T>
MyVector<T>:MyVector(){
    size = 0;
    capacity = 10;
    data = new T[capacity];
}

//my function of shiftLeft
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::shiftRight(){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        data[i+1] = data[i];
    }
    size++;
}
```

this is the requirement for shiftRight function

```
function: shiftRight()
description: shifts all values in the array one space to the right in place (do not allocate a new array)
pre-condition:a MyVector object exists
post-condition: all values are shifted to the right (opens up one space at the beginning of the array)
return: nothing
```

I don't know how to opens up one space at the beginning of the array without allocate a new array

Comment: It looks like your vector's internal array always has exactly `capacity` elements, even if size doesn't report it. So there isn't really any sort of clearing you can do. Just reduce `size` by 1. Maybe assign a default constructed instance to replace it. It's really up to you how you want to handle elements in your array that don't represent objects in your container.

Comment: The requirement doesn't tell about inserting spaces at beggining/end. So, just leave there the current values. Any how, the size (not the capacity) of the shifted array may be updated.

Comment: For the shiftLeft, there actually not a requirement. However, For the shiftRight one, there is one that "to open up one space at the beginning of the array" in the post-condition

Comment: If the requirements are unclear, ask the person who made them to clarify.